# If $A \times B \not = \emptyset$ then there is $a \in A \land b\in B$ so that $\{a,b\} \cap A\times B = \varnothing $ (Axiom of Regularity)

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory

I have been stuck showing the following:(this is in the section in the book on the Axiom of regularity)

> If $A \times B \not = \emptyset$ then there is $a \in A \land b\in B$ so that $\{a,b\} \cap A\times B = \emptyset $

We see that there is $a\in A$ such that $\{a\} \cap A\times B = \emptyset$ Since if that does not hold then we see that $A\subseteq A\times B$ which would mean $A = \emptyset$ (already proven) which can't happen Since $A\times B \not=\emptyset$

Thus to finish the proof:

we need to show that there is a $b \in B$ such that $\{b\} \cap A\times B = \emptyset$

but i can't seem to do this… is it true that if $B \subseteq A \times B$ then $B = \emptyset$?

Comment: Which definition of ordered pairs are you using? The specifics of the proof may depend on which

Comment: The usual kuratowski ordered pair I’m really stuck on this, there’s no way I can see the solution since when $A \subseteq A\times B$ then $A = \emptyset$ the proof relied on the fact that A comes first in the product $A\times B$

Comment: You know what, you gave me a huge hint, I don’t think we can do this (at least so far in the book) with kuratowski definition of ordered pairs. We need to use $\{x ,\{x,y\}\}$ I think?

Comment: Hmm I still can’t see it working

Comment: are still working through this? If so, I can type something up if in a sec

Comment: Yeah I’m still stuck, just fyi the book hasn’t yet mentioned the rank of a set, or sequences of sets, so we can’t use that.

Comment: Are you stuck? It’s tough right, I have no idea how to do it, everything I’m trying just is not working.

Comment: yes its more difficult than I expected at first glance. I have an outline of a solution (or at least I expect it will lend a solution). I have to get something done in the next few hours so I will come back to this

Comment: Ok no problem, I am going to bounty this when it’s time (in 2 hours)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141377/discussion-between-jcal-and-isadisplayname).

Comment: Am I oversimplifying this? $A\times B=\{(a,b): a\in A\text{ and } b\in B\}$ and we are given that $A\times B$ is non-empty. Therefore, by the axiom of regularity, there exists an element $(a,b)\in A\times B$ such that $\{(a,b)\}\cap A\times B$ is empty. Why isn't that sufficient?

Comment: @JohnDouma $(a,b)\not= \{a,b\}$. Also I think you meant $(a,b)\cap A\times B\not = \emptyset$.

Comment: @IsAdisplayName What does it mean to have an element disjoint from a set?

Comment: @JohnDouma the axiom of regularity states : 

    ∀ x ( x ≠ ∅ → ∃ y ( y ∈ x   ∧ y ∩ x = ∅ ) ) .

Comment: @IsAdisplayName I am aware of that. Is $y$ an element of $x$ or is it a set? Either way, I believe this result follows from a direct application of that axiom with $x=A\times B$ and $y=(a,b)$ for some $(a,b)\in A\times B$.

Comment: @JohnDouma (a,b)≠{a,b}, so I don't see how that is true. But if you have a solution, please type it up, I'd love to see it along with op! I am also in the process of typing up a solution, but it is much more complicated, so it would be awesome if I over looked a simple one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have defined $(x, y) = \{x, \{x, y\}\}$ in the comments.

Consider $C = \{\{a, b\} \mid a \in A, b \in B\} \cup (A \times B)$. By the axiom of regularity, take some $c \in C$ such that $c \cap C = \emptyset$.

Since $c \in C$, we have two possibilities. The first is that $c$ is of the form $\{a, b\}$ for some $a \in A$ and $b \in B$. In this case, we have $\{a, b\} \cap (A \times B) \subseteq \{a, b\} \cap C = \emptyset$, and we are done. The second possibility is that $c \in A \times B$. Then write $c = (a, b)$ for some $a \in A$, $b \in B$. Then $\{a, b\} \in c$ and $\{a, b\} \in C$, so $\{a, b\} \in c \cap C$; this contradicts the fact that $c \cap C = \emptyset$.

Comment: Oh nice, this is much more elegant than my solution. It seems like this would work for the kuratowski encoding as well? I.e., if $(a,b)=\{\{a\},\{a,b\}\}$, since we still have $\{a,b\}\in (a,b)$.

Comment: Yes, it also works for that encoding. The only relevant fact is $\forall x \forall y (\{x, y\} \in (x, y))$.

Comment: oh gosh i really like this also

Answer (score 2):

Here is a proof of your desired claim. We proceed by contradiction, so assume your desired claim is false. That is, assume that $A\times B\not=\emptyset$ and
$$(1)\ \forall a\in A \forall b\in B ( \{a,b\}\cap A\times B \not=\emptyset)$$

But $(1)$ is equivalent to

$$(1')\ \forall a\in A \forall b\in B ( a\in A\times B\lor b\in A\times B)$$

As you have already noted (and I will assume without proof), there is an $a_0\in A$ such that $a_0\not\in A\times B$. Instanting $(1')$ on $a_0$ lends:

$$(2)\ \forall b\in B (a_0\in A\times B  \lor b\in A\times B)$$

But since $a_0\not\in A\times B$, we derive:

$$(2')\ \forall b\in B (b\in A\times B)$$

Now we seek to show that $(2')$ contradicts the axiom of regularity. I will do this by showing that a more general situation contradicts the axiom of regularity, and then showing that what we have is an instance of the more general situation. The general situation is the following:

Let $X$ be a non-empty set with the following property:

$$(3)\ \forall x\in X\exists c_x\exists y_x(y_x\in X\land (y_x\in c_x\in x))$$

We can use this property to define an infinite descending chain of sets. An infinite descending chain of sets is a function $f : \mathbb{N}\to V$ (where $V$ is the universe, or some other suitable set) with the property that $f(n+1)\in f(n)$, for each $n\in \mathbb{N}$. The function I will define will also have the property that, for $n=2k$, $f(n)\in X$ (this will be important for the inductive step of the definition).

Since $X$ is non-empty, we have some $x_0\in X$. So we may define $f(0):=x_0$. Now, since $x_0\in X$, we may instantiate $(3)$ on $x_0$ to obtain:

$$(3')\ \exists c_{x_0}\exists y_{x_0}(y_{x_0}\in X\land (y_{x_0}\in c_{x_0}\in x_0))$$

Now, we use choice to select some such $c_{x_0}$ and $y_{x_0}$. We set $f(1):= c_{x_0}$ and $f(2):=y_{x_0}$. Now for the inductive step. We will handle the case that $n$ is even and that $n$ is odd separately. For $n=2k$, we have that $f(n)\in X$. So we instantiate $(3)$ on $f(n)$ to obtain:

$$(3'')\ \exists c_{f(n)}\exists y_{f(n)}(y_{f(n)}\in X\land (y_{f(n)}\in c_{f(n)}\in f(n))$$

We again use choice and set $f(n+1):=c_{f(n)}$ and $f(n+2):=y_{f(n)}$. Now we handle the case when $n=2k+1$. In this case, we have that $n+1=2(k+1)$, so we know $f(n+1)\in X$. So we instantiate $(3)$ on $f(n+1)$ to obtain:

$$(3'')\ \exists c_{f(n+1)}\exists y_{f(n+1)}(y_{f(n+1)}\in X\land (y_{f(n+1)}\in c_{f(n+1)}\in f(n+1)))$$

We again use choice so that we can set $f(n+2):=c_{f(n+1)}$ and $f(n+3):=y_{f(n+1)}$. This completes the definition of $f$. The way I defined $f$ is not technically proper, but it is hopefully clear that we could indeed define $f$ in a proper manner. It is not too hard to verify that $f(n+1)\in f(n)$, for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. [This contradicts the axiom of regularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_regularity#No_infinite_descending_sequence_of_sets_exists). Thus, no such set $X$ can exist.

All that remains to show is that our problem is an instance of this situation. Now, from $(2')$ and the definition of $A\times B$ (using the Kuratowski definition), we obtain:

$$(2'')\ \forall b \in B\exists a'\in A\exists b'\in B (b=\{\{a'\},\{a',b'\}\})$$

We take $c_b:=\{a',b'\}$ and $y_b:=b'$. This indeed lends

$$\forall b\in B\exists  c_b\exists y_b(y_b\in B\land (y_b\in c_b\in b))$$

This completes the proof.

Comment: This looks very good, I will have a read through, the one super frustrating thing about this question is that functions or choice  or even natural numbers have not even been discussed yet! This is a question in section 2.9 of Suppes Axiomatic set theory.

Comment: @JCAL well, you can circumvent the talk of functions and obtain a direct contradiction of regularity. See how wikipedia does it. I'm not sure how to do this without choice, though it may be possible. But I've thought about this question enough for the day, so maybe I'll try to figure that out another time :)

Comment: Your proof can be modified to work without choice, functions, or natural numbers. Suppose $X$ is nonempty and satisfies (3). Define $Y = X \cup \{y \in \bigcup X \mid y \cap X \neq \emptyset\}$. Take $y \in Y$ such that $y \cap Y = \emptyset$, and derive a contradiction.

Comment: @MarkSaving Ah, good to know. If I find myself with time to kill, I might go about making those modifications. 

Still, I have to say, you solution is much better. I would even recommend the OP accept that as the answer...